# Is "have yet to" a modal?

Tags: modal-verbs

It seems to have the function of phrasal modals, but it has limited use and can not be conjugated in other tenses/aspects.

```
I have yet to meet him.
```

Comment: When you say it can't be conjugated, what do you mean? I have yet..., he has yet... Tense: we had yet... How would that compare to [yet](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yet) as an adverb?

Comment: [Collins AED](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/have-yet-to-do-something-) defines the string as:  *have yet to* (do something)
Definitions:
to have not yet (done something)   ⇒ _we have yet to win_. So, as medica suggests, 'yet' is really an adverbial. 'Have to [do something]' usually means 'need to', but not here. I'd say its a non-modal auxiliary usage.

Comment: Yet can't be an adverbial in "have yet to" because if it is removed, it would not have the same meaning at all.

Comment: @William By that analysis, neither is 'still' in 'We have still to win'. You're trotting out a rule-of-thumb that is here throwing up an exception.

Comment: @William I'd amended the comment to shed the ambiguous version.

Comment: The construction doesn't relate to 'We have to do it' but to say 'We missed out the Giant's Causeway – we still have it to do if we're ever in the mood' [ie non-obligatory]. The fact that omitting 'yet' in the original forces a reinterpretation does not mean that 'yet' isn't fulfilling an adverbial role in indicating 'at this time, this is the situation'. On the other hand, 'have yet to' is probably better considered a MWV, as some dictionaries list it.

Comment: ... [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/yet) and YourDictionary class 'yet' as an adverb in this usage: 

1 Up until the present or a specified or implied time; by now or then:
_I haven’t told anyone else yet_ /
_aren’t you ready to go yet?_ / 
_I have yet to be convinced_  [ODO]//// [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/have-yet-to-do-something) does not analyse below 'phrase' level.

Comment: This IS an auxiliary. You may not want to call it a phrasal-modal, but the point is that it has the same grammatical function as modals. There's no other way to analyze "have yet to". Yet is not an adjunct. It completes the phrase.

Comment: "Have still to" is also one.

Answer (score 1):

No, *have yet to* is not a modal. Your perception is correct, however, in that it has something in common with modals. The *have yet to `VP`* construction is a negative idiom, starring the negative polarity item *yet*. Like modals, negatives are Operators, which focus on one particular item in a sentence (normally it's the one that's stressed in speech; in writing it's not so simple).

A sentence like

- *I have yet to see him.*

is transformed from (and means the same as)

- *I have not yet seen him.*

Socially, *have yet to `Vinf`* falutes slightly higher than *have not yet `Vppt`*.
The latter is normal discourse, while the former is redolent of 19th-century prose.

Comment: Why do linguists seem to Capitalize Random Terms of Art? Electrical engineers don't capitalize Volt, architects don't capitalize Frieze,  sailors don't capitalize Transom, mathematicians don't capitalize Set, leathernecks don't capitalize Rig, pirates don't capitalize Booty, etc. (+1 btw)

Comment: I couldn't say why linguists do so. I did so in this case because I usually try to indicate which terms are the important ones. An old professorial habit, I spose. Operators (negatives, modals, and quantifiers of all kinds) constitute something like half of the questions we get here, and we flub most of them.